# Named tuples in a list

Tags: python

I have the following list

```
a = [[a1, b1, c1, [d1, e1, f1],
     [a2, b2, c2, [d2, e2, f2],
     [a3, b3, c3, [d3, e3, f3]]
```

How can I make this into a list of named tuples such that

```
a[0].val1
>>> a1
a[1].val2
>>> b2
a[0].box
>>> [d1, e1, f1]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`collections.namedtuple` class factory](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to create a named tuple class:

```
mynamedtuple = collections.namedtuple('mynamedtuple', ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'box'))

somenamedtuple = mynamedtuple('a1', 'a2', 'a3', ['d1', 'e1', 'f1'])
somenamedtuple.box  # returns ['d1', 'e1', 'f1']
```

You can convert your existing list using a list comprehension:

```
a = [mynamedtuple(*el) for el in a]
```

Comment: So I would have to go through each item in my list? How do I flatten each "row" in the list, such that the result would be of the format you describe after `mynamedtuple`?

Comment: @lejon: I've added an example piece of code that converts your existing lists into named tuples.

Comment: As a side note; what does the `*` do?

Comment: @lejon: Applies each element in `el` as a separate parameter when calling `mynamedtuple()`. if `el` is `[1, 2, 3]`, calling `mynamedtuple(*el)` is like calling it as `mynamedtuple(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: // , Can I assign into the elements of named tuples by reference? Also, in general, are there good ways to quickly see whether a given assignment is by reference or by value?

Comment: @NathanBasanese: named tuples work just like regular tuples: they are immutable. If one of the values referenced is mutable, then yes, you can still mutate that value. Everything in Python is a reference, nothing is ever stored by value.

Answer (score -1):

There is [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) available in collection module.

You can use and create the `namedtuple` which will be referenced by name instead of index of tuple.